# Deletar nó filho no firebase com react-native e redux

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux

Alguém sabe como deletar um item de uma ListView no react-native usando firebase como banco de dados? No caso quero deletar apenas o item marcado no print abaixo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Allison, por favor mostre o código que você tentou usar para deletar.

Comment: Boa tarde Rosário, ainda não tenho um código defenido, pois o que eu tentei apaga todos os registros, e pelo que entendi tenho que ler a chave do registro que quero deletar e depois fazer a ação. Mas ainda não achei um exemplo prático de como fazer isso, pois as chaves criadas no firebase são um tipo de criptografia..agradeço pela atenção e no que puder me ajudar!